# Отправка почты через mail() порциями

Tags: php

Возможно ли такое без подключения phpmailer и подобных? Отправлять нужно порциями по 100 писем каждые 5 минут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phpmailer не плохо справиться с этим... я уже его использовал для рассылки, вроде бы не тормозил, правда там было не 100 где-то половина или чуть больше.

Думаю можно отравлять одну копию всем, но я отправлял каждый новое письмо.
Я делал так:

```
 function MailSend($to, $subj, $txt)    {
              $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
              $mail->IsSMTP(); 
              $mail->Host       = "phh.tj"; // SMTP server
              $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                   
              $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                 
              $mail->Host       = "phh.tj"; 
              $mail->Port       = 25;              
              $mail->Username   = "f@phh.tj"; 
              $mail->Password   = "***";        
              $mail->AddReplyTo('f@phh.tj', 'Mailer prikol.tj');
              $mail->AddAddress($to, 'User');
              $mail->SetFrom('f@phh.tj', 'Mailer prikol.tj');
              $mail->AddReplyTo('f@phh.tj', 'Mailer prikol.tj');
              $mail->Subject =  $subj;
              $mail->MsgHTML('<table cellpadding="10px" width=500px border=0><tr><td width="250px"><img src="http://prikol.tj/images/logo.png" alt=logo /></td><td style="font-family: arial" width="250">'.$txt.'</td></tr>');
              $mail->Send();
            }
```

И все это крутил в цикле списка моих пользователей:

```
$mysql = new db;
        $f=$mysql->query_only_s("SELECT email FROM pr_mailer");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($f))
        {
            $this->MailSend($row['email'], 'Рассылка сайта PRIKOL.TJ', '<p style="font-size: 13px">'.$txt.'</p><p style="font-size: 11px;">Вы можете отписаться от рассылки пройдя по этой <a href="http://prikol.tj/?do=removeEmail">ссылке</a>.</p>');
        }
```

Главное не забывайте include-ить class.phpmailer.php

Comment: а про  phpmailer можно поподробнее как добиться отправки пачками? у хостера лимит стоит на время выполнение скрипта.

Comment: Ну все это я могу реализовать без smtp авторизации а через простую mail() Phpmailer может отправить скажем 100 писем и через час еще 100 писем но уже следующим по списку?

Comment: Это вы уже должны сами реализовать алгоритм, Ведете общий список в базе, выводите данных (пример: SELECT id, mail WHERE sts!=1 LIMIT 100) затем при каждой отправке письма указываете, что ему вы уже отправили(присвистываете sts=1 каждому отправленному). Запускать с задержкой можно только с cron-ом если вам хостер предоставляет такую возможность. Я понять не могу, вам нужны готовые коды или просто помочь с Алгоритмом?

Comment: Спасибо алгоритм понял. просто думал что phpmailer сам может хранить список тех кому отправил и кому нужно отправить. У хостера лимиты стоят на отправку 100 писем в час. думал на сайте сделать уведомление о том что появилось новое задание. но с лимитами это не возможно проще уж через твиттер организовать...

Comment: phmailer отправлять будет через вашу почту, думаю хостер ну может контролировать это попробуйте. Так как он использует не стандартные фу-ци php.

Comment: Хотя пообщавшись с службой поддержки выяснилось что каждое письмо можно отправит не более 100 адресам. итого 10000. буду писать код с циклом в цикле... А smtp не работает fsockopen у них заблокирован...

Comment: А чем вам не нравится SMTP? его можно настроить на разные почтовые серверы... mail.ru, gmail.com итд... PHPMailer это умеет! там уже будет зависеть от почтовых серверов. закинете в список несколько почтовиков и отсылаете от них по очереди...

Answer (score 0):

Ну, сделайте скрипт с задержками. Либо настройте крон. Вариантов - море.

Answer (score 0):

Настройте крон, самый простой способ.

Comment: Через cron я не пойму как? там же массив с адресами. получается что он одним и тем же отсылать будет...

Comment: 1. Скрипт вызывается по крону
2. Проверяется кому отправил и кому надо отправить
3. Выбирается 100 и отправляется
4. Эти 100 отправленных добавляются к уже отправленным и больше отправляться не будут.

Нужно только продумать как хранить список отправленных, но это уже зависит от системы, можно в базе, можно в мемкэше.